# How to deal with negative eigenvalue in a kernel matrix?

Tags: r, math

here is my code:

```
> toy=cbind(rnorm(50), rnorm(50))
> K=kernelMatrix(x=toy, rbfdot()) 
> min(eigen(K)$values)
```

As expected the answer is positive. but changing the kernel function do vanilladot result in:

```
> K=kernelMatrix(x=toy, vanilladot()) ; min(eigen(K)$values)
[1] -3.528788e-15
```

If I understood correctly, this must be positif or zero (positif definiteness of linear kernel), and this is small and can be du to computational issues with floats and should be zero.
What can I do to overcome this problem ? I need this matrix to be semi definite positive for the rest of script (Cholesky decomposition, and quadratic programming)

Comment: -3.528788e-15 is effectively zero. You should say what packages you are using. Just set such values to zero.

Comment: the only package I load manually is [kernlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/index.html). I only need _kernelMatrix()_ related functions for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific (toy) example, you can wrap the whole procedure in a loop until your data doesn't have this problem.

```
repeat {
    # you don't need 2 rnorm calls
    toy <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=2)
    K <- kernelMatrix(x=toy, vanilladot())
    if(min(eigen(K)$values) > 0) break
}
```

Note that `kernelMatrix` in this case returns a matrix which is `X %*% t(X)` where `X` is your original input data. Such a matrix will only have 2 positive eigenvalues, with all the rest being numerically zero. You should *expect* to get negative numbers due to floating-point error, and plenty of them. You probably want to reconsider what you're trying to do.

Comment: Indeed I have at most 2 non-zero eigenvalues. I just want the other to be zero and not almost-zero due to floating-point error. My toy set is just for testing porpuse, it is Ok to change it until I get non negative eigen-values. But when I will use real data, it won't be possible any more.

Answer (score 0):

`-3e-15` is close enough to zero that I think its safe to assume you're running into float error.  Take a lok at the results of

```
all.equal(min(eign(K)$values), 0)
```

You can also always fix this number to zero using a quick check too.

```
x <- min(eign(K)$values
if (all.equal(x, 0)) {
  x <- 0
}
```

Comment: The problem is if further procedures will also be using the raw data, and calculating the eigendecomposition themselves. Just changing the output from `eigen` won't help with that.

Comment: Why wouldn't it?  You've just gotta include checks for very small values (positive or negative) and change them to zeros... If I'm missing something please feel free to ask a second question with much more specifics about what you're doing and why this answer doesn't work.

Comment: I want to do things like `chol(K)` just after. It is not possible if K is not non-negative. I don't know how this kind of test is perform, but if it is made as I just did (`min(eigen(K)$values)<0`), it won't work

Comment: @Justin: I thin ManuH may need to know whether there is a method to alter the QR components so that passing them to subsequent methods lets them pass tests for semi-positive-definiteness. It might not be the case that simply coercion of the eigen-vectors to zero will succeed. Perhaps calculating a generalized inverse would be a route around this difficulty?